# Any suggestions on Cluster management?

Tags: load-balancing, cluster

I need some suggestions on cluster management: tools list(like heartbeat, pacemaker, openqrm), management strategy.

Answer (score 1):

generic one: do monitor regularly if fail-over works. there is no worse surprise than learning that your hot-standby node actually does not work when you need it.